# Angular currency code not working on older Angular version

Tags: angular, currency-pipe

I am using Angular 7.3.x and updating is not an option and I'm wondering if that has something to do with this.

Basically:

`{{ value | currency:'USD' }}` gives me $

`{{ value | currency:'EUR' }}` gives me euro sign

also tried some others like Korea, UK

but I'm trying to format it to Malaysian ringgits with
`{{ value | currency:'MYR' }}` which just gives me 'MYR(value)' when I would expect 'RM(value)'

Is this because I'm using an old Angular version? I can't find documentation for this version, just the most up to date docs, which according to them, this should totally work.
https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-currency-pipe-formatting-currency-in-angular/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp looks like I should have been using `{{ value | currency : 'MYR' : 'symbol-narrow' }}` to get the proper 'RM' I was expecting